# How to Place cursor inside "Region" which is created using VSIX Extensibility

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console, vsix, vs-extensibility

```
eg: REGION
    | //Cursor should be here 
    END REGION
```

Up on creating Region ,cursor point should be placed automatically inside the created Region as like in the normal Visual Studio
, I am using VSIX Extensibility using visual studio 2017

I tried

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y); //but it is not working
```

Please give the solution. Thanks in Advance

Comment: How exactly are you creating/inserting this text into the VS code window? 

Note, the Console class is for console based output, and is not related to the Visual Studio code editor.

Answer (score 0):

To change caret position in the current Visual Studio editor, use the following code:

```
EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveDocument?.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
ts?.MoveToLineAndOffset(line, column);
```